Generating deterministic ECDSA/RSA keys based on seed and salt using zero-dependencies
Given seed and salt how do I produce a set of deterministic ECDSA keys using zero-dependencies JavaScript and SubtleCrypto?
(This is a continuation of this question.)
My understanding is that there're two major ways to go about it:

Generate the key material and then somehow import it as ECDSA keys.
Generate x & y required to generate ECDSA keys (I'm not sure how, given that generateKey accepts just named curves; maybe via JWK?)

I'd like the solution to rely as much as possible on the SubtleCrypto API with as little custom code as possible.
The code:
async function generateDeterministicECDSAKey(seed, salt) {
    // Step 1: Convert seed and salt to ArrayBuffers
    const enc = new TextEncoder();
    const seedBuffer = enc.encode(seed); // Seed as a buffer
    const saltBuffer = enc.encode(salt); // Salt as a buffer

    // Step 2: Derive key material using PBKDF2
    const baseKey = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
        'raw',
        seedBuffer,
        { name: 'PBKDF2' },
        false,
        ['deriveBits', 'deriveKey']
    );

    // Derive 256 bits (32 bytes) of key material for the private key
    const derivedBits = await crypto.subtle.deriveBits(
        {
            name: 'PBKDF2',
            salt: saltBuffer,  // Salt for PBKDF2
            iterations: 100000, // Use a secure iteration count
            hash: 'SHA-256'     // Hash function for PBKDF2
        },
        baseKey,
        256  // 256 bits for the derived key
    );

    // Step 3: Import derived key material as ECDSA private key
    // NOTE - that's where it fails due to a mismatch between the "raw" format
    // and  { name: 'ECDSA', namedCurve: 'P-256' } algo
    const privateKey = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
        'raw',
        derivedBits,  // Use derived bits as private key
        { name: 'ECDSA', namedCurve: 'P-256' },  // ECDSA using the P-256 curve
        true,  // Mark key as exportable
        ['sign']  // Key usage for signing
    );

    // Step 4: Export the private key in PKCS8 format (optional)
    const pkcs8Key = await crypto.subtle.exportKey('pkcs8', privateKey);
    
    // Step 5: Generate public key pair (optional)
    const publicKey = await crypto.subtle.exportKey('jwk', privateKey);

    return {
        privateKey: privateKey,
        pkcs8Key: pkcs8Key,
        publicKey: publicKey
    };
}

// Helper function to convert ArrayBuffer to base64 string (for display)
function arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
    const binary = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(buffer));
    return window.btoa(binary);
}

// Example usage
const seed = "your_deterministic_seed"; // Example seed
const salt = "your_salt_value";         // Example salt
await generateDeterministicECDSAKey(seed, salt).then(keys => {
    const privateKeyBase64 = arrayBufferToBase64(keys.pkcs8Key);
    console.log("Private Key (PKCS8 Base64):", privateKeyBase64);
    console.log("Public Key (JWK):", keys.publicKey);
});


For browsers that support private PKCS#8 keys without public component (e.g. Chrome), you have already posted a working approach in the linked question (you only need to use a valid key, see comments).

For browsers that only support private PKCS#8 keys with public component due to a bug (e.g. Firefox), the public component must be determined from the private key. It is advisable to use a reputable library with the required functionality. Alternatively, you can implement this yourself with the corresponding effort and the risk of security vulnerabilities and performance issues.

@Topaco - the issue is I need to generate a public key, it's can I get an end to end solution please? Also I'd like to see if generating X & Y (or generating an importable JWT) path can be easier/will have less custom code?

Your key derivation only generates the private key. You must determine the public key from the private key as pointed out above (using a library or your own implementation). For browsers that support a PKCS#8 key without public component, the public key can be determined e.g. from the exported key in JWK format

I understand that, is it possible to do that using zero-dependencies JS? I'm posting the entire chunk of code I have so we can test it end to end.

I would swear that I've already written this in a comment to one of your earlier questions, but I can't find it now. You will have to write your own code to perform elliptic curve point addition and scalar multiplication. This can be done with the aid of the comparatively impoverished but nevertheless adequate Javascript BigInt type. I would guess it could be done in 100 lines of JS code or less for the NIST curves.

BigInt is vulnerable to timing attacks, here, JSBN may be more suitable.

Are there known vulnerabilities  linked to generateKey  ECDSA call?

Not that I know of, but generateKey() is not deterministic, it generates a different key pair each time.

It is indeed. But choosing between having deterministic but vulnerable and sound nondeterministic keys I choose the latter. The path I'm considering is to use JWKs - private JWK has got just on extra attribute on top of the public one, so I nominate it as a secret. Can you see any issues with this approach? Losing password recovery is a painful one indeed. I wonder if there're any reversed-BIP39 algos, allowing to generate a human readable data based on private value, which can be used for password restoration, I'd be really keen on looking at it.

You can generate an ECDSA key pair deterministically via PBKDF2 or a mnemonic (BIP 39). This is not the problem, but rather that you want to achieve this exclusively with the WebCrypto API, which simply does not provide the required functionality (or is not implemented correctly in various browsers). The solution would be to use a library that supports the required functionality, either directly or as a blueprint for a custom implementation.

Regarding JWKs: I'm not quite sure what you're actually asking. Of course you can use JWKs. The private key contains the raw private key (d) in addition to the public key (containing the raw public key: x, y), which is described in detail in RFC 7518, sec. 6.2..

On the one hand you want all major browsers, for some of which (e.g. Firefox/Safari) a library with EC arithmetic is necessary to determine the public key from the private key, on the other hand you don't want any additional libraries. Your requirements are somewhat contradictory.

OK. never mind ECs, can it be done for asymmetric RSA keys? Even thought you said before that JWT might be a solution for it as it works consistently across the browsers.

Here you will find an approach based on node-forge. The idea is to use the built-in key pair generator, but not to initialize it with a random seed, but with the deterministically generated one. Unfortunately, WebCrypto does not offer a key pair generator that could be initialized in this way. Either you use a suitable library or you have to completely re-implement the key generation yourself (with the usual risks such as side-channel attacks, performance issues etc.). Maybe others have a better idea.

Where I've said that JWKs work consistently across the browsers? JWK is a way to extract the public key from the private key, provided that the browser supports private keys with a public key component.

Sorry it was a different lad. But hey, cool down :) Thanks. So am I out of options here? Generate calls won't accept seed and RSA cannot be imported using importKey do I understand it right?

For EC keys, a deterministic derivation is simple in principle. It is your restrictions that make the problem difficult to solve. You should either do without some browsers (Firefox, Safari) or use an additional library that provides the functionalities to support these browsers. For RSA, deterministic key derivation is more difficult in my estimation, unless you can build on a ready-made implementation as in the node-forge example linked above.

Main reasons for having deterministic keys are: 1. to be able to derive an account name from the public key. 2. restore keys using mnemonic. Are there any alternative to deterministic keys which'd allow to achieve the above 2 points?

I have written such a code a while ago, is it still possible to submit an answer on that eventhough the bounty has ended? If so I will dive into some drives to find the snippet.

let's try if it works I'll pay 500 no problem.

Alright, once I found it, I'll submit an answer

thank you. please make sure it works in chrome, opera and edge.

You've shot yourself in the foot. If you had restricted the browsers to Chrome, Edge and Opera earlier, an answer would probably have been posted long ago, as your requirements are easy to implement for Chrome (as well as for Edge and Opera). But who gets the idea from a description like ...working across major browsers... that just the problem browsers Safari and Firefox are excluded? Safari has a market share of 40% (like Chome), Firefox of 5% (like Edge).

Hehe haven't seen trolls with score like yours before... Chrome, Edge and Opera will do me, post the answer and I'll reward with with 500. P.S. Don't by shy to ask, it doesn't byte.

Calm down mates :D I wasn't able to find the exact script I was looking for, but I found something else. I uploaded it to a github repo: https://github.com/RayRizzling/js-ecdsa

thanks a lot. what browsers it won't work if any please?

I have written a readme. but basically in close to any modern browser. just to name some: Google Chrome (from v 37), Mozilla Firefox (from v 34), Microsoft Edge (from v 12), Safari (from v 7), Opera (from v 24)

If it's helpful and is close enough to what you have been looking for let me know, so I will post the repo as an answer to this question

Thanks for this. How difficult would it be to convert x, y and d to the format used by subtle crypto JWK so the key can be imported using subtle crypto import method and then used with sign/verify methods - I can be wrong but it feels like that'd save a lot pain? Also one real minor point - can we convert params to a func so we could pass curve name like P-256, P384 or P-521 to match those natively supported by subtle crypto?

Absolutely, my ultimate goal is to get it working with subtle crypto methods like - import, sign and verify. for the obvious reason I can't use generate() method, but I'd like use all the applicable methods coming with the CryptoKey object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CryptoKey. Ideally I'd like use it for encrypting too, since such possibility is presented, but we might need another bounty for this lol. Please post the answer I'll accept, you've gone long lengths already with it.

I added JWK functions as well. but for dynamic support of other curves the complete code needs changes. for byte lenght and such. Like you said that would be good for another bounty. I might take that as well, if I have the time.

thanks again. I'll create another bounty shortly to cover up the rest of ECDSA curve types supported by subtle crypto, including  P-384 and P-521 and ideally Ed25519 (or any other PQC ones). Am I right in thinking that your implementation would effortlessly support encrypt/decrypt once the key is imported with the right usages?

This code was created as a comprehensive answer to the question covering an educational example of ECDSA without any external modules working in most modern browsers.
Raw Code:
index.html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ECDSA with Deterministic Key Generation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Deterministic ECDSA Keys</h1>
    <label for="seed">Seed:</label>
    <input type="text" id="seed" placeholder="Enter your seed"><br><br>
    <label for="salt">Salt:</label>
    <input type="text" id="salt" placeholder="Enter your salt"><br><br>
    <button onclick="generateKeys()">Generate Keys</button><br><br>
    
    <label for="message">Message to Sign:</label>
    <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="Enter your message"><br><br>
    <button onclick="signMessage()">Sign</button><br><br>

    <button onclick="convertToJWK()">Convert to JWK</button>
    <button onclick="verifyWithCryptoAPI()">Verify with Crypto API</button><br><br>

    <div id="output"></div>

    <script src="math.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

script.js
// Constants for the P-256 curve (secp256r1 or prime256v1)
const n = BigInt("0xFFFFFFFF00000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBCE6FAADA7179E84F3B9CAC2FC632551"); // Curve order (n)
const P = BigInt("0xffffffff00000001000000000000000000000000ffffffffffffffffffffffff"); // Prime field modulus (P)
const A = BigInt("0xffffffff00000001000000000000000000000000fffffffffffffffffffffffc"); // Curve coefficient A
const B = BigInt("0x5ac635d8aa3a93e7b3ebbd55769886bc651d06b0cc53b0f63bce3c3e27d2604b"); // Curve coefficient B
const G = { 
    x: BigInt("0x6b17d1f2e12c4247f8bce6e563a440f277037d812deb33a0f4a13945d898c296"), // Generator point X-coordinate (G)
    y: BigInt("0x4fe342e2fe1a7f9b8ee7eb4a7c0f9e162bce33576b315ececbb6406837bf51f5")  // Generator point Y-coordinate (G)
};

// Generate deterministic private key from the seed and salt using SHA-256
async function generateKeys() {
    const seed = document.getElementById('seed').value;
    const salt = document.getElementById('salt').value;

    if (!seed || !salt) {
        alert("Please enter both seed and salt!");
        return;
    }

    const enc = new TextEncoder();
    let privateKey = BigInt(0);
    do {
        // Derive the private key using SHA-256 with the seed and salt
        const derivedBits = await crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", enc.encode(seed + salt));
        privateKey = BigInt("0x" + Array.from(new Uint8Array(derivedBits))
            .map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, "0")).join("")) % n; // Ensure private key is within range [0, n-1]
    } while (privateKey <= 0n || privateKey >= n); // Keep trying until a valid private key is generated

    const publicKey = pointMult(privateKey, G); // Generate the corresponding public key using scalar multiplication
    if (!publicKey || !validatePoint(publicKey)) {
        alert("Invalid public key generated!");
        return;
    }

    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = `
        <h3>Private Key:</h3>
        <pre id="privateKey">${privateKey.toString(16)}</pre>
        <h3>Public Key:</h3>
        <pre id="publicKey">${JSON.stringify({ x: publicKey.x.toString(16), y: publicKey.y.toString(16) }, null, 2)}</pre>
    `;
}

function constantTimeCompare(a, b) {
    if (a.length !== b.length) return false;
    let result = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        result |= a[i] ^ b[i]; // XOR operation: If any bit differs, the result will be non-zero
    }
    return result === 0;
}

// Validate a point on the elliptic curve (check if it satisfies the curve equation)
function validatePoint(point) {
    if (point === null) return true;
    const { x, y } = point;
    const lhs = mod(y ** 2n, P); // Left-hand side of the curve equation: y^2 mod p
    const rhs = mod(x ** 3n + A * x + B, P); // Right-hand side of the curve equation: x^3 + A * x + B mod p
    return lhs === rhs;
}

// Generate a random k for the signature process
function generateRandomK() {
    const array = new Uint8Array(32); // 32 bytes = 256 bits
    crypto.getRandomValues(array); // Generate random bytes
    let k = BigInt("0x" + Array.from(array).map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join(''));
    return k % n; // Ensure k is within the valid range [1, n-1]
}

// Sign a message using the private key
async function signMessage() {
    const message = document.getElementById('message').value;
    const privateKeyHex = document.getElementById('privateKey').textContent;

    if (!privateKeyHex) {
        alert("Please generate a key pair first!");
        return;
    }
    if (!message) {
        alert("Please enter a message!");
        return;
    }

    const prevSignatureEntry = document.getElementById('signature-container');
    if (prevSignatureEntry) {
        prevSignatureEntry.remove();
    }

    console.time("signMessage");
    const privateKey = BigInt("0x" + privateKeyHex); // Convert the private key from hex to BigInt

    // Hash the message using SHA-256
    const messageHashArrayBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", new TextEncoder().encode(message));
    const messageHashArray = new Uint8Array(messageHashArrayBuffer);
    const messageHash = BigInt("0x" + Array.from(messageHashArray)
        .map(byte => byte.toString(16).padStart(2, '0'))
        .join(''));

    // Compute the signature
    let k = generateRandomK(); // Generate a random k for signing
    const rPoint = pointMult(k, G); // Compute the elliptic curve point k*G
    const r = rPoint.x % n; // r is the x-coordinate of the point mod n

    const s = mod(((messageHash + r * privateKey) * modInv(k, n)) % n, n); // Compute the signature parameter s
    k = null;
    console.timeEnd("signMessage");

    const signature = JSON.stringify({ r: r.toString(16), s: s.toString(16) });

    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += `
        <div id="signature-container">
            <h3>Signature:</h3>
            <pre id="signature">${signature}</pre>
        </div>
    `;

    const isValid = await verifySignature();
    const signatureContainer = document.getElementById('signature-container');

    // Change the background color based on the validity of the signature
    if (isValid) {
        signatureContainer.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    } else {
        signatureContainer.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }

}

// Verify the signature using the public key
async function verifySignature() {
    const message = document.getElementById('message').value;
    const signatureText = document.getElementById('signature').textContent;

    if (!signatureText) {
        alert("No signature found!");
        return false;
    }

    // Retrieve the public key
    const publicKeyElement = document.getElementById('publicKey');
    if (!publicKeyElement) {
        alert("Public key has not been generated yet.");
        return false;
    }

    const publicKeyJSON = JSON.parse(publicKeyElement.textContent);

    console.time("verifySignature");
    const publicKey = {
        x: BigInt("0x" + publicKeyJSON.x),
        y: BigInt("0x" + publicKeyJSON.y)
    };

    const signature = JSON.parse(signatureText);
    const r = BigInt("0x" + signature.r);
    const s = BigInt("0x" + signature.s);

    // Check if r and s are within the valid range
    if (r <= 0n || r >= n || s <= 0n || s >= n) {
        alert("Invalid signature values");
        return false;
    }

    // 1. Compute the hash of the message
    const msgHash = await crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", new TextEncoder().encode(message));
    const msgHashBigInt = BigInt("0x" + Array.from(new Uint8Array(msgHash)).map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, "0")).join(""));

    // 2. Calculate w = s^(-1) mod n
    const w = modInv(s, n);

    // 3. Calculate u1 = H(m) * w mod n and u2 = r * w mod n
    const u1 = (msgHashBigInt * w) % n;
    const u2 = (r * w) % n;

    // 4. Calculate the point P = u1 * G + u2 * Q
    const pointP = pointAdd(pointMult(u1, G), pointMult(u2, publicKey));

    // 5. Check if r == xP mod n using constant-time comparison
    const xP = pointP.x % n;
    const rHex = r.toString(16).padStart(64, '0'); // Ensure r is in a consistent format (hex)
    console.timeEnd("verifySignature");

    // Compare xP and r in constant time
    if (constantTimeCompare(rHex, xP.toString(16).padStart(64, '0'))) {
        console.log("Signature is valid.");
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log("Signature is invalid.");
        return false;
    }
}

function toJWK(privateKey, publicKey, curveName) {
    const base64UrlEncode = (buffer) =>
        btoa(String.fromCharCode(...buffer))
            .replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/=+$/, '');

    const hexToUint8Array = (hex) =>
        new Uint8Array(hex.match(/.{1,2}/g).map(byte => parseInt(byte, 16)));

    const xArray = publicKey.x.toString(16).padStart(64, '0');
    const yArray = publicKey.y.toString(16).padStart(64, '0');
    const dArray = privateKey ? privateKey.toString(16).padStart(64, '0') : null;

    return {
        kty: 'EC',
        crv: curveName,
        x: base64UrlEncode(hexToUint8Array(xArray)),
        y: base64UrlEncode(hexToUint8Array(yArray)),
        ...(privateKey ? { d: base64UrlEncode(hexToUint8Array(dArray)) } : {})
    };
}

function convertToJWK() {
    const privateKeyHex = document.getElementById('privateKey')?.textContent;
    const publicKeyJSON = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('publicKey')?.textContent);

    if (!privateKeyHex || !publicKeyJSON) {
        alert("Generate keys first!");
        return;
    }

    const privateKey = BigInt("0x" + privateKeyHex);
    const publicKey = {
        x: BigInt("0x" + publicKeyJSON.x),
        y: BigInt("0x" + publicKeyJSON.y)
    };

    const jwk = toJWK(privateKey, publicKey, "P-256");
    console.log("Generated JWK:", jwk);
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += `
        <h3>JWK:</h3>
        <pre id="jwkText">${JSON.stringify(jwk, null, 2)}</pre>
    `;
}

async function verifyWithCryptoAPI() {
    const jwkText = document.getElementById('jwkText').textContent;
    const signatureText = document.getElementById('signature').textContent;
    const message = document.getElementById('message').value;

    if (!jwkText || !signatureText || !message) {
        alert("Make sure keys, signature, and message are available!");
        return;
    }

    const jwk = JSON.parse(jwkText);
    const signature = JSON.parse(signatureText);

    try {
        const cryptoKey = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
            "jwk",
            {
                kty: jwk.kty,
                crv: jwk.crv,
                x: jwk.x,
                y: jwk.y,
            },
            { name: "ECDSA", namedCurve: jwk.crv },
            false,
            ["verify"]
        );

        const encoder = new TextEncoder();
        const data = encoder.encode(message);

        const r = BigInt("0x" + signature.r);
        const s = BigInt("0x" + signature.s);
        const rBytes = new Uint8Array(r.toString(16).padStart(64, '0').match(/.{2}/g).map(byte => parseInt(byte, 16)));
        const sBytes = new Uint8Array(s.toString(16).padStart(64, '0').match(/.{2}/g).map(byte => parseInt(byte, 16)));
        const sigBytes = new Uint8Array([...rBytes, ...sBytes]);

        const isValid = await crypto.subtle.verify(
            { name: "ECDSA", hash: { name: "SHA-256" } },
            cryptoKey,
            sigBytes,
            data
        );

        alert(`Verification result: ${isValid}`);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error during verification:", err);
        alert("Verification failed!");
    }
}

math.js
// Modular arithmetic functions for the elliptic curve operations

// Modulo operation to handle negative results correctly
function mod(a, m) {
    return ((a % m) + m) % m;
}

// Subtraction in modular space
function modSub(a, b, m) {
    return mod(a - b, m);
}

// Multiplication in modular space
function modMult(a, b, p) {
    return mod(a * b, p);
}

// Modular inverse using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm
function modInv(a, p) {
    if (a === 0n) throw new Error("Modular inverse is not defined for 0");

    let t = 0n, newT = 1n;
    let r = p, newR = a % p;

    // Extended Euclidean Algorithm to find the inverse of 'a' modulo 'p'
    while (newR !== 0n) {
        const quotient = r / newR;
        [t, newT] = [newT, t - quotient * newT];
        [r, newR] = [newR, r - quotient * newR];
    }

    // If the greatest common divisor is greater than 1, no modular inverse exists
    if (r > 1n) throw new Error("Element not invertible");

    // Ensure the result is positive
    if (t < 0n) t += p;

    return t;
}

// Elliptic curve point addition (Weierstrass equation)
function pointAdd(p1, p2) {
    if (p1 === null) return p2; // If p1 is the identity (point at infinity), return p2
    if (p2 === null) return p1; // If p2 is the identity, return p1
    if (p1.x === p2.x && mod(p1.y + p2.y, P) === 0n) return null; // If p1 and p2 are inverses, return the identity

    let lambda;
    if (p1.x === p2.x && p1.y === p2.y) {
        // Point doubling
        const num = 3n * mod(p1.x ** 2n, P) + A; // Formula for point doubling: λ = (3 * x1^2 + A) / 2y1
        const denom = modInv(2n * p1.y, P); // Denominator is the modular inverse of 2y1
        lambda = modMult(num, denom, P);
    } else {
        // Regular point addition
        const num = modSub(p2.y, p1.y, P); // y2 - y1
        const denom = modInv(modSub(p2.x, p1.x, P), P); // x2 - x1
        lambda = modMult(num, denom, P); // λ = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
    }

    // Calculate the new point coordinates
    const x3 = mod(lambda ** 2n - p1.x - p2.x, P); // x3 = λ^2 - x1 - x2
    const y3 = mod(lambda * modSub(p1.x, x3, P) - p1.y, P); // y3 = λ(x1 - x3) - y1
    return { x: x3, y: y3 };
}

// Elliptic curve point multiplication (scalar multiplication)
function pointMult(k, point) {
    let result = null;
    let addend = point;

    // Perform the binary method for scalar multiplication
    while (k > 0n) {
        if (k & 1n) {
            result = pointAdd(result, addend); // Add the point to the result if the corresponding bit is 1
        }
        addend = pointAdd(addend, addend); // Double the point (equivalent to shift left in binary)
        k >>= 1n; // Right shift to process the next bit of k
    }
    
    return result;
}

